Error authentication failure invalid_grant on username-password flow for Data Cloud mulesoft connection
When implementing Mulesoft to Data Cloud integration, got the following error
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}

when trying to follow Username-password flow
https://domain.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
-H Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body
grant_type:password
client_id:3MV...CLIENT_ID
client_secret:F9...SECRET
username:user@name.com
password:{password}{security-token}

What is the reason for this error?

On some orgs, in
OAuth and OpenID Connect Settings
checkbox Allow OAuth Username-Password Flows in unchecked

It must be checked for Username-Password flow, which is required for MuleSoft to Data Cloud integration (it doesn't support Client Credentials flow as of Winter 25).

After this setting is checked, the error is gone and token is generated.
{
    "access_token": "00DNS000005zcLe!AW--Access_Token__--random-bits",
    "instance_url": "https://domain.my.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00DNS000005zcLe2AI/005NS000004UaQLYA0",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1731583120525",
    "signature": "FI-singature--8="
}


Username/Password flow should not be used - it's insecure and has been outlawed by future revisions of oAuth spec. This is why Salesforce introduced the toggle and defaulted it to off. Mule Data Cloud connector 1.2 supports JWT flow, the recommended option for server-to-server calls into Data Cloud.

I personally prefer client credentials flow over JWT flow. However, client credentials flow is not supported by Mulesoft

@identigral for now we are building POC, so we can potentially postpone migration to JWT flow later. I agree we will have to move to JWT Flow or maybe till that time Mulesoft starts supporting client credentials flow which I prefer personally
